# Tor dimension in polynomial rings over Artin rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I found this tricky problem in trying to understand some properties of local rings at non-smooth points of embedded curves. But this would be a very long story. So I make it short and I try to go directly to the question.

Fix a field $k$, of characteristic $0$ and consider the ring of power series in $n+1$ variables, $B=k[[x, y_1, \ldots, y_n]]$. Let $a> 1$ be an integer and let $I$ be the ideal of $B$ given by the equations $x=y_n^{a}$ and $y_i^a= g_i(x,y_i)$ for some $g_i\in k[[x, y_i]]$ for $i=1, \ldots, n-1$. Suppose that $B/I$ is a regular (local) ring (I'm not totally sure that this is my case, but one has to start somewhere).

Let now $A=k[x]/(x^m)$ be my favorite Artin local ring. Is it true that the module
$$M=\frac{k[[x, y_1,\ldots, y_n]]}{(x^m, x=y_n^{a}, y_i^a= g_i(x,y_i), i=1,\ldots, n-1)}$$
has finite (projective) homological dimension over $A[[y_1, \ldots, y_n]]$, i.e. it admits a finite projective resolution?

This question can also be a reference request: if you know where I can find something useful I would also be very happy!

**Note:** I've asked this question on MO. I got two up votes but no answers.

Comment: I've written an answer to the MO question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158639/tor-dimension-in-polynomial-rings-over-artin-rings)